# C++ multiple big files in one binary file

Tags: c++, file, format, copying

What is an efficient way to store multiple big files (100Mo to 5Go) in one binary file in c++ ?
For example, if I have an audio file, a very large image file, and a text file, I want to create a binary file that contains these three files and be able to retrieve them latter (to recreate the three original files).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Define _efficient_ first. By which means, size, performance?

Comment: There are far too many correct answers to this question. I don't think it can be properly answered.

Comment: Yes sorry, efficient in the sense that the files can be between 100Mo and 5Go...

Comment: On linux try `sendfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**.

The long answer is it depends on how you want to package these things, what framing you want to use.

Do you need compression? Do you need random access? One way that's easy to implement is just using the zip container, it's well defined and there's a lot of libraries for creating and manipulating them. The same goes for the [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) or [cpio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) format.

The alternative is to write your own container format. This is a lot more difficult, you'll have to write an archiver and extractor.